# Add fading vertical submenu to a one page html with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, submenu

I want to add a vertical submenu to a menu I have.

I would like to have [this effect](http://jsfiddle.net/mhJXt/279/) when hovering....

I added some code but is not working what should I add (do not want those icons)
just the efecct, but I do not seem to acommplish the task, is there a way to add a fade effect to that submenu?

[The jsfiddle is this](http://jsfiddle.net/9c58k/31/)

```
<div id="header-wrap">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#main">Init   </a></li>
                 <li><a href="#services">Services</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about-us">about us  </a></li>
                 <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

               <ul class="submenu">
                  <li><a href="#services-1">Service1</a></li>
                 <br>
                 <li><a href="#services-2">Service2</a></li>
                 <br>
                <li><a href="#services-3">Service3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fade effect is due to a CSS3 property known as `transition` (you may have to use vendor prefixes). It has nothing to do with jQuery.